# E-Mail Header: MIME-Version: 1.0 - When should this be used?

Tags: email, mime, email-headers

This could be rightfully construed as a beginner's question.

Consider the following e-mail header:

> MIME-Version: 1.0

My Questions:

- When should you stamp an e-mail with this header?
- When should you *omit* this e-mail header?

**EDIT:** Is it true that whenever you specify a 'Content Type' header, no matter what that content type happens to be, that you should also specify 'MIME-Version'? [[This link](http://en.kioskea.net/contents/courrier-electronique/mime.php3) tipped me off to the possibility.]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), you should use the 'MIME-Version: 1.0' heading when you're sending an e-mail that contains one of the following:

- Text in character sets other than
  ASCII
- Non-text attachments
- Message bodies with multiple parts
- Header information in non-ASCII character
  sets